# javascript実行後のURLを取得する

Tags: javascript, php, html, bash

HTML+Javascriptのページがあります。このページにはvideoタグで動画が再生されるのですが、動画のURLはjavascriptの実行により動画URLがvideoタグにセットされる構成になっています。

このvideoタグにセットされるURLを取得したいと思っています。
bashもしくはPHPを使って、ページURLからjavascriptを実行して生成される動画url(mp4)を取得するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

やりたいことは以下のイメージです。

```
$ getmovieurl.sh http://aaa.com/aaa.html
http://bbb.com/ccc.mp4
```

関連ページ情報でもかいません。ご存知の方はご教授いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

スクレイピング関連を調べるのが良いかと思います。

例えば、以下の記事では PhantomJS を用いてレンダリング後の HTML を取得する様子を示しています。
https://qiita.com/_RJ/items/de57cf2a7602b64ffed9

Comment: まさにやりたいことはスクレイピングです。  phantomjs phantomjs-get-html.js http://<サーチしたいサイト> > temp.html  としても(phantomjs-get-html.jsはサイトの通り作成済み)該当の動画URLがtemp.htmlの中でヒットしません。

Comment: PhntomJS の内部は WebKit です。基本的にはブラウザのレンダリングと相違ありませんので、レンダー後の DOM ノードが異なるという事は何かしらの操作ないしパラメーターが不足しているのだと思います。
   PhantomJS の出力と Chrome 等の WebKit 系ブラウザのデベロッパーツールで閲覧できる DOM ノードと比較してみると良いかも知れません。

Comment: 想定ですが、javascriptにより非同期で動画URLを取得して、videoタグに値をセットしているようです。この場合、Phantomjsを使ってhtmlを表示しても出力されません。Phantomjsを使ってjavascriptを動作させないといけないことはわかりましたが、値を参照するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: `想定ですが、javascriptにより非同期で動画URLを取得して、videoタグに値をセットしているようです。` この部分を明確にし、発生条件を調べるしかないと思います。ブラウザにできている事ですので、後は丁寧に調査できるかどうかの問題です。